# Powershell 5.1: alias descriptions are missing in my module

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a module `PhriInfrastructure` which codifies our DevOps procedures at my organization.  It has a function `Test-IsLocalhost` that I've aliased to `Get-IsLocalhost` for backwards-compatibility reasons.

I've tried to apply a `description` to the alias, like so:

```
New-Alias -Name Get-IsLocalhost -Value Test-IsLocalhost -Description "Get-IsLocalhost was renamed Test-IsLocalhost to better-match Powershell verb standards"
```

however, when I try to pull metadata about the alias in the command-line

```
Import-Module .\PowerShellModules\src\PhriInfrastructure -Force
(Get-Alias Get-IsLocalhost) | Format-List -Property *
Get-Help Get-IsLocalhost
```

the `Description` field is empty in both the `Get-Help` and the `Get-Alias` (the underlying `Test-IsLocalhost` command only has a `#.Synopsis`.

Meanwhile, if I attempt to create the alias direct from command-line, it appears in the alias members (but still not in the get-help).

Is there a way to expose the alias description properly?  Or some better way to say "don't use this alias, use the primary one?"  Is this just a bug in how Powershell 5.1 exports aliases in modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, whatever `-Description` value you specify seems to be lost when an alias is exported *from a module* (observed in Windows PowerShell and in PowerShell (Core) up to a least v7.3.6, current as of this writing).

> Is this just a bug in how PowerShell 5.1 exports aliases in modules?

I'd say yes, and I encourage you to create a bug report [in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues).

> if I attempt to create the alias direct from command-line, it appears in the alias members (but **still not in `get-help`**).

By design, aliases don't have their own help - `Get-Help` simply resolves an alias to its target command and shows *its* help, so you'll never get information about the alias itself that way.

> some better way to say "don't use this alias, use the primary one?"

- Generally, the `.Description` property of alias definitions is rarely used (it isn't set for any of the *built in* aliases), which is also suggested by the fact that it doesn't even surface in `Get-Alias`'s for-display output unless you explicitly ask for it (e.g., via `Format-List *`)
- You could implement `Get-IsLocalhost` as a *function* that delegates to `Test-IsLocalHost`, which allows you to provide its own comment-based help, which could be as simple as:

  ```
  function Get-IsLocalHost {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Get-IsLocalhost was renamed Test-IsLocalhost to better-match PowerShell verb standards.
  #>
    Test-IsLocalHost @args
  }
  ```

  - If you prefer a *runtime* warning, you can use the [`System.ObsoleteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ObsoleteAttribute) attribute as follows; note that the comment-based help is used to automatically forward to `Test-IsLocalHost`'s help here:

    ```
    function Get-IsLocalHost {
    <#
    .ForwardHelpTargetName Test-IsLocalHost
    .ForwardHelpCategory Function
    #>
      [Obsolete("Get-IsLocalhost was renamed Test-IsLocalhost to better-match PowerShell verb standards.")]
      param()
      Test-IsLocalHost @args
    }
    ```
  - On invocation, a warning is unconditionally emitted via the Warning [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), which can be silenced with `3>$null` (if you wanted to also support `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue`, you'd have to make the function an *advanced* one, which would require duplicating the target function's parameter declarations, and invoking it with `Test-IsLocalHost @PSBoundParameters`.)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Implementing deprecated aliases as full functions seems painfully verbose.  I'm just going to explain that the aliases are deprecated previous names for the function in the comment-generated help .NOTES or .DESCRIPTION section.  I know the PS Core team is working on a proper workflow for deprecation but it's WIP.

Comment: @Pxtl, turns out there _is_ a way to deprecate, resulting in a runtime warning. The proxy function can actually be quite simple, depending on your needs - please see my update.